# SimpleMessageListenerContainer still picks up a message after calling stop

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-messaging, spring-cloud-aws

I have an **AWS SQS Queue** with no retry (**MaxReceiveCount** is set 1). I have setup a **DeadLetter Queue** for the same.

I am using **spring-cloud-aws-messaging**, below is my listener class

```
@Component
public class MyListener implements ProcessingFinaliser {

    private final String sourceQueue;
    private final MyProcessor myProcessor;
    private SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer;

    public Mylistener(@Value("${my.queue}") String sourceQueue, 
                        MyProcessor myProcessor,
                        SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer) {
        this.sourceQueue = sourceQueue;
        this.myProcessor = myProcessor;
        this.simpleMessageListenerContainer = simpleMessageListenerContainer;
    }

    @SqsListener("${my.queue}")
    public void doWork(String message) throws MyCustomException {
        this.processor.processMessage(messge);
    }

    // Called when shutdown signal is called
    @Override
    public void finaliseProcessing() {
        simpleMessageListenerContainer.stop(sourceQueue);       
    }

}
```

**SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory#waitTimeOut** is set to **20 seconds**
`simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory.setWaitTimeOut(20);`

The problem I am facing is that when **simpleMessageListenerContainer.stop(sourceQueue)** the **doWork** method still picks up a new message and goes to DeadLetter Queue as the **container dies**. Looks like the underlying **PollingThread** in **SimpleMessageListenerContainer** does not stop straight away.

By default the **SimpleMessageContainerListener#queueStopTimeout** is set to **10 seconds**, would setting this to 0 be the right thing to do?

Can someone explain please?